# multi step survey with setState - need help storing data in object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a survey of 20 questions.
I'm trying to store the responses in an object using useState hook.
Spent some time on it but can't quite figure it out.

Made a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/radio-group-control-b5qil0?file=/src/First.tsx

Parent - Form.tsx

```js
export default function Form () {
   const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

   // Maybe I can use array here, will try it later
   const [formData, setFormData] = useState(
      {
         '1': '', 
         '2': '', 
         ...
      }
   );

   const questions = {
      1: 'You enjoy constantly meeting new people',
      2: 'You enjoy artistic endeavors and activities',
      ...
   }

   const conditionalComponent = () => {
      switch (page) {
         case 1:
            return <First questions={questions} formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
         case 2:
            return <Second questions={questions} formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
         ...
```

Child - FirstQuestion.tsx

```js
return (
   <Text>{questions['1']}</Text>

   <Radio.Group
      value={formData['1']}
      // Can't figure out this part
      onChange={() => {
         setFormData({
           ...formData,
           1: formData['1'],
         });
       }}
   >
```

The Radio Group is a Mantine component:
https://mantine.dev/core/radio/#controlled-radiogroup

Comment: `Spent some time on it but can't quite figure it out.` > What exactly are you not able to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code in your `Radio.Group`

```
onChange={(value) => {
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        1: value
      });
    }}
```

I checked in your code sandbox and it works.